# Android Custom notification RemotView uses no Styles

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-notifications

I try to create a custom notfification with remote views that can be expanded and has different TextViews and Buttons. That works well but most of the fields in the layout don't use the styles.
After spending 4+ hours on searching and try to fix it, the only thing  I found is an issue in google code that describes this error:

https://**code.google.com**/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1894

Has anyone an idea how to solve this or bypass this?

I tried to use my styles or the android styles, without any styles...
It looks like the it depends on the postion of the field, because in the expaned version the first field accepts the style.

**My Test Code**

Create the notification

```
       NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // set the view layout
        RemoteViews remoteViewsNotification = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_non_expanded);
        remoteViewsNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_test_field_1, "non-expanded");

        RemoteViews remoteViewsExpandedNotification = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.notification_expanded);
        remoteViewsExpandedNotification.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_test_field_1, "expanded");


        // create a new notification intent and set the actions
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TrainingInProgress.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        // Create the notification and set all values
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContent(remoteViewsNotification)
                .setSmallIcon(sportsIconId)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true).build();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            notification.bigContentView = remoteViewsExpandedNotification;
        }

        notificationManager.notify(notifyId, notification);
```

XML  notification_non_expanded

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_2"
        android:layout_below="@id/notification_test_field_1"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Line2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_3"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_test_field_1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_4"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_test_field_2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

XML  notification_expanded

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_1"
        style="@style/mainHeadlineBigTextStyleDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_2"
        android:layout_below="@id/notification_test_field_1"
        style="@style/mainHeadlineBigTextStyleDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_3"
        style="@style/mainHeadlineBigTextStyleDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_test_field_1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification_test_field_4"
        style="@style/mainHeadlineBigTextStyleDark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Test Field 4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification_test_field_2"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Style i used for testing

```
<style name="mainHeadlineBigTextStyleDark">
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mainHeadlineBigTextColorDark</item>
</style>


 <color name="mainHeadlineBigTextColorDark">#747474</color>
```

Comment: set background color of RelativeLayout may help

Comment: i tried this already and it helped not. it could be only a workaround to change it to a dark color to make readable but i want to use the common design ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spendung a few more hours, i have found the error...

If you provide the text for the TextView by the xml hint field:

```
    android:hint="Test Field 1"
```

and don't override or set the text by

```
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "TEXT");
```

Then is the, in the xml selected, Style not applied and the text keep white.

Because i was working with dummy text for creating the  layout i haven't recognize this early...